# How to launch more than 6 virtual terminals in void linux

Tags: linux, terminal, tty, init

I would like to have more virtual terminals start at startup.
I want to be able to use runit and do

```
ln -s /etc/sv/agetty-tty7 /var/service/agetty-tty7
ln -s /etc/sv/agetty-tty8 /var/service/agetty-tty8
```

but `/etc/sv` only has ttys up to 6.

I've tried adding `TTYS=8` to my `rc.conf` and rebooting but still `/etc/sv` only has 6 ttys

Any advice?

Comment: If extra terminals supposed to be used in the same session, IMHO it better to use ``tmux`` terminal multiplexer and create there as many virtual terminals as you needed

Comment: As a clue, many linux's distros use terminals 7 and/or 8 for desktop, try to skip 7&8 and add it as 9, 10...

Answer (score 0):

[Answered on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/voidlinux/comments/90h14o/how_to_launch_more_than_6_virtual_terminals_in/)

```
cp -Rvp /etc/sv/agetty-tty6 /etc/sv/agetty-tty9
unlink /etc/sv/agetty-tty9/supervise
ln -s /etc/sv/agetty-tty9 /var/service
```